# Can't read or write CDs with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, drive, cd, burning

The USB DVD-RAM writer, DVDRRW GSA-2166D, has the capability to play and burn CDs.
But under Ubuntu 20.04 whilst it plays DVDs,the device is not recognised at all by VLC when an audio CD is inserted. Trying with paranoia, it recognises the drive, but cannot read the contents table.
When a blank CDRW disk is inserted, and XfBurn is set up to write an audio CD, it cannot find the device.
Is there a fix or has Ubuntu given up on reading and writing CDs as opposed to DVDs?

Comment: Is your model number from a label on the device, or from a report like lshw or lsusb?  You can waste a lot of time if a wrong label is on the device.

Comment: (The site software does not let me add a comment. So as answer:) Ubuntu (and Linux) quite surely did not give up on operating CD media.
More probable is a problem between drive and medium.
What message lines do you get from this shell command while the blank
CD is inserted: <pre><code>xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -toc</code></pre>

Comment: Can you test this with a live usb of Ubuntu 20.10 or possibly other Linux distro as it could be something wrong in your installation. Ubuntu still has the ability to burn CDs.